# Why does moving symlinked directory A to symlinked directory B cause A to be moved inside B?

Tags: shell, symlink, overwrite, mv, ln

Scenario: I'm writing a shell script that checks to see if a directory exists; if it does, and it's a symlink, it renames the directory with `.bak` appended to the directory name. I noticed, however, that if I'm moving a symlinked directory (directory A) to another symlinked directory (B), it causes A to be moved *inside* B, rather than overwriting B.

To illustrate:

```
$ mkdir foo                                                                     
$ mkdir bar                                                                     
$ ln -s "$PWD/foo" ~/.baz                                                       
$ ls -al ~/.baz                                                                 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ysim  staff  15 Sep 11 21:45 /Users/ysim/.baz -> /Users/ysim/foo  
$ mv ~/.baz ~/.bam                                                              
$ ls -al ~/.bam                                                                 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ysim  staff  15 Sep 11 21:45 /Users/ysim/.bam -> /Users/ysim/foo  
$ ls -al ~/.baz                                                                 
ls: /Users/ysim/.baz: No such file or directory                                                                                                   
$ ln -s "$PWD/bar" ~/.baz                                                       
$ ls -al ~/.baz                                                                 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ysim  staff  15 Sep 11 21:47 /Users/ysim/.baz -> /Users/ysim/bar  
$ ls -al ~/.bam                                                                 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ysim  staff  15 Sep 11 21:45 /Users/ysim/.bam -> /Users/ysim/foo
```

Now, when I rename/move `~/.baz` to `~/.bam`:

```
$ mv ~/.baz ~/.bam
```

The target of `~/.baz` (`/Users/ysim/bar`) doesn't get moved to the target of `~/.bam`, as expected:

```
$ ls -al ~/.bam                                                                 
lrwxr-xr-x  1 ysim  staff  15 Sep 11 21:45 /Users/ysim/.bam -> /Users/ysim/foo
```

Instead, the entire `~/.baz` symlink has been moved *inside* the `~/.bam` directory:

```
$ ls -al ~/.bam/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 ysim  staff   102 Sep 11 21:47 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 96 ysim  staff  3264 Sep 11 21:51 ..
lrwxr-xr-x   1 ysim  staff    15 Sep 11 21:47 .baz -> /Users/ysim/bar
```

Why is that? And how do I go about doing what I set out to do, which is to write the target of `~/.baz` to the target of `~/.bam`, so that `~/.bam` has the destination `/Users/ysim/bar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works like that because `mv` asks the OS to do the moving, and the OS dereferences symlinks. To behave differently `mv` would need extra code to check for symlinks and some `--dereference-target`, `--dereference-src` (or such) options. Think about the number of different behaviours different users might find desirable.

You need

```
rm "$dest"
cp -a "$src" "$dest"
# in your case src=".bam" and dest=".baz"
```

BTW if in a script you want to

- "read" the target of a symlink in a script: `target=$(readlink "$f")`
- test whether a file is a symlink: `test -l "$f"`

Comment: Ah, I see. So, for example -- and correct me if I'm wrong -- it would be unclear whether you wanted to move the source of A to the source of B like I want to do (`~/.bam -> /Users/ysim/bar`), or the target of A to the target of B (`~/.baz -> /Users/ysim/foo`), or to have `~/.bam` go away completely (only `~/.baz -> ~/bar`).

Comment: It would be unclear *if* `mv` decided to do anything beyond what the OS/libc provides. But `mv` *doesn't*, probably because like you said there would be many confusing options :)